# How to prevent nesting of json objects in API

Tags: json, rest, spring-rest

I have a spring boot application with frontend and backend connected using apache HttpClient.
There are many bi-directional associations between the entities. For example:

```
    @NamedEntityGraphs(
    {
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.ApplicationUserProcesses",
            attributeNodes ={
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "processes", subgraph = "processes"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "roles")
            },
            subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = "processes",
                attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("applicationUsers")
                })
        )
    }
)

public class ApplicationUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "app_user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applicationUsers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Process> processes = new HashSet<>();
}





public class Process  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "membership",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "process_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The process and applicationUser entities have bi-directional association as shown above. The issue is that when the backend returns applicationUser object, there is continuous nesting of objects in the json (as shown below) which is not needed. How to make the json API from the backend stop nesting.

```
    applicationUser:{
    processes:[{
        process1:{
            applicationUser:{
                processes:[{
                    process1:{
                    
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Is there anyway to prevent the nesting of objects in the json and maintain clean API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jackson's `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotation to avoid that.

On parent class where you want to allow child to be included in **JSON** add `@JsonManagedReference` annotation.

```java
public class ApplicationUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "app_user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applicationUsers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Process> processes = new HashSet<>();

}
```

On child class where you don't want to include parent in **JSON** add `@JsonBackReference`.

```java
public class Process  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "membership",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "process_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

You should not expose the entity to **API** instead use **DTO/VO** which are **POJO** classes that holds the values. Try using different **POJO** classes based on how you want to expose your entity relationship. Or try to avoid bidirectional relationship in entity as generally not required as you will always get child from parent or vice versa.

Comment: **DTOs** - reduces payload for your clients, and improves performance by including only the data you need. **POJO** - make your code more readable and easier to understand. makes your code decoupled, makes it easier to test (as you do not need any framerowks), and since they are not tied to any frameworks you can reuse it in different layrs of your applications. more on that just google or look at this small post: https://www.baeldung.com/java-pojo-class

Comment: @Dhaval Gajjar, this directional association is needed for the application to work correctly.